# Facebook Messanger Integration

Tags: android, android-facebook

I am working on Facebook messenger integration. When a user presses the reply button in Messenger, it navigates to my app's second screen. After that, when I select another image in the grid view on the main screen and move to the second screen again to send to Messenger, then the reply functionality is not working and it closing the second screen due to `MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger()` with out any warning and error. Reply will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

look at here you might be get some tips. and use socialauth sdk

http://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/part-1-using-socialauth-to-integrate-facebook-api-in-android

Answer (score 1):

MessengerUtils.finishShareToMessenger(ACTIVITY, shareToMessengerParams);

Here, ACTIVITY is the activity that received the original intent from Messenger i.e the first activity in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have `android:launchMode="singleInstance"`, but

> Activities that run with this launch mode don't allow others to start them for a result.

so
you need to change your launchMode of activity in AndroidManifest.xml to  `android:launchMode="standart"` or `android:launchMode="singleTop"`

[Similar question](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1664247843850847/)